# Angular 6 /Javascript - Calling two methods in (nglick). Component and Js

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular6, angular7

I'm trying to make two calls in my `click` event, where these calls would be one for my component and another for my javascript function. Below is my code:.

Event click Angular:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="Plans(); " [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed"
aria-controls="collapseBasic">Test</button>
```

My component.ts:

```
Plans(){
      this.limparCombinadoList();
      this.codCombinadoPadrao = "dgc" + this.value.toString();
      this.service.combinadoTipoRisco(this.codCombinadoPadrao)
      .subscribe(
                result  => {
                this.coberturas = result.data;
                this.premioFinalCobertura = result.premioFinalCombinado
                this.processarDados(this.coberturas,this.premioFinalCobertura)
            });
    }
```

My Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function renderDiv(){
    $.BrunoLeite.init('[data-animation]');
  }
</script>
```

My javascript file

hs.onscroll-animation.js

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';

   $.BrunoLeite = {

    /**
     * Base configuration.
     *
     * @var Object _baseConfig
     */
    _baseConfig: {
      bounds: -100,
      debounce: 50,
...

}}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for `alerta2` to be outside of the angular context?

Comment: @briosheje was an example call in javascript

Comment: Yes. I updated the post with what I need. Thanks for the support.

Comment: You realize that `angular` has an animation module, yes? https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: @theheadrush, Yes. I'm importing a template that I have in hml5 / bootstrap, where after the click event, I perform the service call and render a child componenet with the new data

Comment: @BrunoLeite Seems like intentionally complicating the situation by mixing paradigms.

Comment: @theheadrush, Yes it's an animation for every time my div is updated. I perform call to a service that updates my div with new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `alerta2` function inside the component and call it from `(click)` event.

```
 alerta2(){
   alert("Bruno Leite")
 }


(click)="Plans();alerta2();"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the 2 separated with a `;`, like that:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="Plans(); alerta2();" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed"
aria-controls="collapseBasic">Test</button>
```

Moreover, you have to move your function `alerta` in your `component.ts` file, changing:

```
function alerta2() {
    alert("Bruno Leite")
}
```

to:

```
alerta2() {
    console.log("Bruno Leite")
}
```

Comment: How would I put Javascript inside a .ts file?

Comment: Change `function alerta2() {alert("Bruno Leite") }` to `alerta2() {console.log("Bruno Leite") }`

Comment: Sorry, I put an example of a javascript call, but what I need is not an alert function but call a function that is in another file. A call to this function is:

$ .BrunoLeite.init ('[data animation]');

I will update my post